# mysql: data truncated error from time value: function

Tags: mysql, function

My function is has two variables ('date', number of months to subtract from 'date').

here is my function:

```
create function a_testbed.PrevMonth (
in_date         date,
in_mn_count     int)
RETURNS int
BEGIN
/* local variable declaration */
declare v_date         int(255);
declare v_date_format  varchar(10);
declare v_date_sub     varchar(10);

set v_date_format := DATE_FORMAT(v_date, '%Y-%m');
set v_date_sub := DATE_FORMAT(curdate(), '%Y-%m');

if (in_date is null) then
  set v_date := v_date_sub;
elseif (in_mn_count is null or in_mn_count < 0) then
  set in_mn_count := 0;
else
  set v_date := v_date_sub;
end if;
RETURN v_date_format;
END;
#
```

Keep getting the error:

```
ERROR 1265 (01000) Data Truncated for column 'v_date' at row 1
```

any thoughts?
thanks!

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: ERROR 1265 (01000) Data Truncated for column 'v_date' at row 1

Comment: Is there a reason you need your own function to do this? Why is this returning an INT rather than a DATE? MySQL has builtin functions and expressions to subtract months from a date, e.g. `dateexpr + INTERVAL -n MONTH`.

Comment: If the purpose of the function is to throw a `Data truncated` error, that can be accomplished with a lot less code.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of things wrong with your function:

1. You do `set v_date_format := DATE_FORMAT(v_date, '%Y-%m');`, but this is before you assignea value to `v_date`.
2. Later you assign `set v_date := v_date_sub;`, but you never use `v_date` after that, so what is the point?
3. You assign `set in_mn_count := 0;`, but never use this variable, either.
4. Finally you do `RETURN v_date_format;`. `v_date_format` is a `VARCHAR`, but the function is declared to return `INT`. And the contents of this string is in the form `YYYY-MM`, so it doesn't look like an integer.

I'm not sure if any of these are causing the `Data truncated` error, but that hardly seems to be important when the function is so broken.

Comment: My brain processed this function, and threw an exception: "`5150 What the plastic?`"

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe "`INT(255)`" is a valid datatype.

I know the 255 is just a display width attribute. The INT datatype defines the range of values, the display width doesn't impact the range of values. But I've just never seen the length modifier on an INT larger than 11. (10 for an unsigned int) (?)

As a test, you could try specifying `INT(11)`, or just `INT`.

More problematic, perhaps, is that this variable with datatype `INT` is being passed as the first argument to `DATE_FORMAT` function. But the first argument of `DATE_FORMAT` needs to be a `DATE`, `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` (iirc).  There may be some implicit conversion from INT to DATE, but I don't think there is.

---

I don't understand why you need a function to subtract a number of months from a DATE. MySQL has builtin in functions, and simple expressions that do that.

For example:

dateexpr + INTERVAL -6 MONTH

returns a DATE (or DATETIME) value with 6 months subtracted from `dateexpr`.
If you need to "round down" to the first of the month, or convert to a string with just the 'yyyy-mm', you can do a `DATE_FORMAT(dateexpr,'%Y-%m-01')` or a `SUBSTRING(dateexpr,1,7)`, respectively.

---

**review**

```
CREATE FUNCTION a_testbed.PrevMonth (
in_date         date,
in_mn_count     int)
```

That looks okay, two input parameters, a DATE and an INT. (Function parameters are always IN parameters.)

```
RETURNS int
```

A bit odd that a function named `PrevMonth` takes a DATE argument, but returns an INT, rather than a DATE, but this isn't an error.

```
BEGIN
/* local variable declaration */
DECLARE v_date         INT(255);
```

The display width of 255 is bizzarre. Never seen that on an INT before.

```
DECLARE v_date_format  VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE v_date_sub     VARCHAR(10);
```

Two strings, looks fine.

```
SET v_date_format := DATE_FORMAT(v_date, '%Y-%m');
                                 ^^^^^^
```

But `v_date` is an INT, not a DATE or DATETIME. And it's not initialized, so it's NULL. If this doesn't throw an exception, then we'd expect `v_date_format` to be NULL. (I suspect you wanted to specify `in_date` here in place of `v_date`.)

```
SET v_date_sub := DATE_FORMAT(curdate(), '%Y-%m');
```

This should get us 7 characters, e.g. '2013-07'. So no problem there.

```
IF (in_date IS NULL) THEN
    SET v_date := v_date_sub;
```

Here's a usage of the `in_date` parameter. Check if it's null. If it is, assign the same 7 characters that we assigned to v_date_sub. Got it.

```
ELSEIF (in_mn_count IS NULL OR in_mn_count < 0) THEN
    SET in_mn_count := 0;
```

Is it valid to assign a value to an IN parameter? (That may be valid, but it is odd. Normally we don't assign values to parameters unless they are OUT, or INOUT paremeters. We normally assign values to procedure variables (and sometimes MySQL user variables.)

Why is this dependent on whether in_date is null or not (the preceding IF). Seems like we would want to check this parameter in either case.

```
ELSE
  SET v_date := v_date_sub;
```

Isn't this the same action specified under the first `IF`?  It seems like the logic here reads "if in_date is not null and ifnull(in_mn_count,-1)<0" we do one thing, else we do somthing else. We're either trying to assign a value to an IN parameter, or we're assigning current YYYY-MM to v_date.

```
END IF;
```

So far, the only use of the in_date parameter has been to check if it is NULL. And the only usage of the in_mn_count parameter has been to try to assign a zero to it, if it's null or less than zero.

```
RETURN v_date_format;
```

The only time we assigned anything to `v_date_format` was at the beginning of the function, when we assigned the return from a DATE_FORMAT function, passing in a NULL value (as an INT rather than a DATE.)  So what was all the other code supposed to be doing?

```
END
```

Yes, please, end. There is so much wrong in this function, it makes my head hurt. So, please, yes, END. Just make it stop.

Comment: I think you spent more time criticising this function than he spent writing it. :)

Comment: @Barmar: I was trying to figure out what it was doing. And I still haven't a clue as to WHY it's doing it. This has to be the most ingenious way of throwing a `'Data truncated'` error that I have ever encountered. (BTW... I upvoted your answer.)

Answer (score 0):

You assign varchar to int `set v_date := v_date_sub;`
Change this:

```
declare v_date         varchar(10);
```

Comment: But assigning a VARCHAR to an INT shouldn't be throwing an exception. MySQL reads character by character until it can't convert to integer. If the VARCHAR contains '1234', then the INT gets a value of 1234. If the VARCHAR contains '1A2B3C', then the INT gets a value of 1.